# No Devices in VS Code - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to flutter app devleopment. I've installed Flutter SDK and I'm using VS Code. I want to test my demo app in my android device, I've enabled Developer mode and USB debugging option in my android device. In the status bar, VS Code shows, **No Device** though I connected via USB cable. How to resolve this problem? Do we need Android SDK for this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH5uQ.png)

Comment: You need to do debug configuration on your mobile

Answer (score 2):

connect your phone then you need to run `adb devices` on command line while your phone is unlocked it will show allow debug alert on phone accept and it will show

you can download command line tools and use [sdk manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) if you don't have android sdk 
[image: from android studio page]

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed D. Sherif, Now I can see my device name.. But while executing **flutter run**  it throws error like this...                                                                      
  Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components

Comment: But flutter doctor shows... 
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

Comment: the message is very clear you must have android studio from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html installed and setup the sdk after install

Comment: Can we download Android sdk alone?

Comment: i edited my answer to show how but this method is hard

Answer (score 1):

Run VS Code as administrator.

Check the result from terminal output: flutter doctor

Comment: naah. its still missing from my bottom bar. there's no device option